# Send Google Protocol buffer messages between C# and Java

Tags: java, c#, sockets, rabbitmq, protocol-buffers

I am trying to get a good sample program to send Google protocol buffer messages to and from Java server to c# client. I an using RabbitMQ for this purpose, but I found that RabbitMq service is not that reliable, and crashes some time. As a backup I want to use socket option in case RabbitMq is down. 
I have code like this in java

```
ProtoBuffMessage.MessageProtBuff msgItem = clsBuilder.build();
ByteArrayOutputStream oStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
msgItem.writeTo(oStream);
...  
...
//Send it to RabbitMQ
m_clsChannel.basicPublish(m_clsAppSettings.getRabbitMqExchangeName(), m_clsAppSettings.getRabbitMqExchangeQueue(), null, oStream.toByteArray());
```

on C# side I have code like this to receive and parse the data

```
     using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "direct_logs",
                                    type: "direct");
            var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;



            channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName,
                              exchange: "direct_logs",
                              routingKey: "amr");

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                    {
                        var body = ea.Body;
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                            var routingKey = ea.RoutingKey;
                            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}':'{1}'",
                                              routingKey, message);


                            Messaging.MessageProtBuff.Builder builder = new Messaging.MessageProtBuff.Builder();
                            builder.MergeFrom(body);

                            Messaging.MessageProtBuff data = builder.Build();
                                Console.WriteLine(data.Comment);
                    }
         }
```

This works with RabbitMq if it is working properly. Now I want to know How do I use sockets to send the same, and receive it at C# client and reconstruct the Object. Preferably I would like to use the same ByteArrayOutputStream oStream object in java code. By converting it to byte array I can send it over the scocket and reconstruct the object at other end.
I have adapted this sample in my code:
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html](http://Knock%20Knock%20Server)

but in this tutorial they are sending strings. I want to send the byte array. How to do this at java end and how to parse the same at C# end?

Comment: "RabbitMq service is not that reliable, and crashes some time" - have you figured out why?

Comment: @AlexeyGroshev I am not expert in RabbitMQ. It will take time to investigate that and that is something we don't have at the moment. It seems to be problem with Erlang, possibly memory issues but we are not sure. If you can tell us how to investigate that, let us know.

Comment: > It seems to be problem with Erlang, possibly memory issues but we are
> not sure


There are no Erlang memory problems. The memory problems related to RabbitMQ are often related to wrong configurations/tuning. 

> I found that RabbitMQ service is not that reliable, and crashes some
> time
 

Two major problems was fixed to version `3.6.4`:

 - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/issues/245
 - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/issues/185

These bugs happened only under certain load conditions.

Cluster configuration prevent any possible crash problem